# Android, How to read QR code in my application?

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code, implicit

In my application I need to read Qr code. I searched the net and found Zing codes however lots of developers had problem with using it and it seems it is buggy!

If i assume that my customers has qr reader installed on their device, how can i use those applications and call them via implicit intents?

if user doesn't have any qr reader, what will happen to the application? if it crashes, may i ask user to download for example QrDroid and after that use it?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
try {

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

} catch (Exception e) {

    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
    startActivity(marketIntent);

}
```

and in `onActivityResult():`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {           
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            //handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Little typo: you added an extra L to "canceled"

Comment: @SeshuVinay but for this we will need the BARCODE SCANNER app installed in the phone

Comment: @SeshuVinay can you tell me how to store data after scanning .

Answer (score 34):

Zxing is an excellent library to perform Qr code scanning and generation.
The following implementation uses Zxing library to scan the QR code image Don't forget to add following dependency in the build.gradle

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
```

Code scanner activity:

```swift
    public class QrCodeScanner extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
        private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
            super.onCreate(state);
            // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
            // Set the scanner view as the content view
            setContentView(mScannerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
            mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            // Start camera on resume
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            // Stop camera on pause
            mScannerView.stopCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
            // Do something with the result here
            // Prints scan results
            Logger.verbose("result", rawResult.getText());
            // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)
            Logger.verbose("result", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
            //If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
            //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_QR_CODE, rawResult.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is in the application, this should the the accepted answer

Comment: If you get a white screen, try "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />" in the <manifest> section of your AndroidManifest.xml, as described at https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner.

Comment: Just a informative update. Please keep track on the update of the version no of the library too.

Comment: AppConstants.KEY_QR_CODE - "AppConstants" is unresolved

Comment: @AndrewSnejovski AppConstants.KEY_QR_CODE is just a constant maintained in constant file. you can define your own. it is used as a key to send  back the result data to the calling activity. where the required data is fetched in onActivityResult on the basis of that key.

Answer (score 31):

> if user doesn't have any qr reader, what will happen to the application? if it crashes, may i ask user to download for example QrDroid and after that use it?

Interestingly, Google now introduced [Mobile Vision APIs](https://developers.google.com/vision/), they are integrated in play services itself.

In your Gradle file just add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.0'
```

Taken from this [QR code tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2016/09/android-example-programmatically-scan-qr-code-and-bar-code/).

**UPDATE 2020:**

Now QR code scanning is also a part of ML Kit, so you can bundle the model inside the app and use it by integrating the following gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Use this dependency to bundle the model with your app
  implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.0.3'
}
```

Or you can use the following gradle dependency to dynamically download the models from Google Play Services:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Use this dependency to use the dynamically downloaded model in Google Play Services
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:16.1.2'
}
```

Taken from [this link](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android).

Comment: This requires Google Services installed on the target device, which not all phones have.

Comment: @LeonardoAcevedo Google play services have a very high adoption rate i.e 90% + also now its been a while since this feature has been released. So should not be a problem at all now.

Comment: I doubt that Play Services adoption can get that much adoption with China banning their use, but in any case it is not an integral part of Android and should not be considered as such

Answer (score 20):

**In android studio, You can use bellow process to create & Read QR Code**  &image look like bellw
[image]

1. Create a android studio empty project
2. Add library in app.gradle

   ```
   compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
   compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
   ```
3. In activity.main xml use bellow..

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.enamul.qrcode.MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_margin="20dp"
     android:orientation="vertical">


   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:hint="Enter Text Here" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
       android:text="Click Here TO generate qr code"
       android:textAllCaps="false"
       android:textSize="16sp" />


   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnScan"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
       android:text="Scan Your QR Code"
       android:textAllCaps="false"
       android:textSize="16sp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_qr_readTxt"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. In MainActivity you can use bellow code

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ImageView imageView;
     Button button;
     Button btnScan;
     EditText editText;
     String EditTextValue ;
     Thread thread ;
     public final static int QRcodeWidth = 350 ;
     Bitmap bitmap ;

     TextView tv_qr_readTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
       button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
       btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        tv_qr_readTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_qr_readTxt);

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {



           if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
               EditTextValue = editText.getText().toString();

               try {
                   bitmap = TextToImageEncode(EditTextValue);

                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

               } catch (WriterException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           else{
               editText.requestFocus();
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Your Scanned Test" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

         }
     });


   btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
           integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
           integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
           integrator.setCameraId(0);
           integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
           integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
           integrator.initiateScan();

        }
      });
       }


    Bitmap TextToImageEncode(String Value) throws WriterException {
      BitMatrix bitMatrix;
       try {
       bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
               Value,
               BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX.QR_CODE,
               QRcodeWidth, QRcodeWidth, null
       );

       } catch (IllegalArgumentException Illegalargumentexception) {

        return null;
      }
     int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();

     int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();

     int[] pixels = new int[bitMatrixWidth * bitMatrixHeight];

     for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
         int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;

        for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {

            pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ?
                   getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeBlackColor):getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeWhiteColor);
         }
       }
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

      bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 350, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);
      return bitmap;
   }




     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if(result != null) {
       if(result.getContents() == null) {
           Log.e("Scan*******", "Cancelled scan");

        } else {
           Log.e("Scan", "Scanned");

           tv_qr_readTxt.setText(result.getContents());
           Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     } else {
         // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
      }
    }
   ```
5. You can download full source code from GitHub. GitHub link is :  https://github.com/enamul95/QRCode

Comment: Thanks! I had to install SDK 26 to build your project. Works nice. Also updated versions of libraries to 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3' and 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0@aar'. How can your rate be 1, if you have many positive answers?

Comment: After scanning its going back to home page. I'm using this code in fragemnts!

Answer (score 6):

I've created a simple example tutorial. You can read this and use in your application.

http://ribinsandroidhelper.blogspot.in/2013/03/qr-code-reading-on-your-application.html

Through this link you can download the qrcode library project and import into your workspace and add library to your project

and copy this code to your activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     if (requestCode == 0) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
             Toast.makeText(this, contents,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             // Handle successful scan
         } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             //Handle cancel
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you expand your answer? Near link-only answers are not useful if the link ever goes broken.

Comment: hi my answer is edited you can go through this and you should look the url link in the answer

Comment: It says the file is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Use a QR library like ZXing... I had very good experience with it, QrDroid is much buggier. If you must rely on an external reader, rely on a standard one like Google Goggles!

Answer (score 2):

## Easy QR Code Library

A simple Android Easy QR Code Library. It is very easy to use, to use this library follow these steps.

### For Gradle:

Step 1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Step 2. Add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.mrasif:easyqrlibrary:v1.0.0'
}
```

#### For Maven:

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Step 2. Add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mrasif</groupId>
    <artifactId>easyqrlibrary</artifactId>
    <version>v1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### For SBT:

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build.sbt file:

```
resolvers += "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io"
```

Step 2. Add the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.mrasif" % "easyqrlibrary" % "v1.0.0"
```

#### For Leiningen:

Step 1. Add it in your project.clj at the end of repositories:

```
:repositories [["jitpack" "https://jitpack.io"]]
```

Step 2. Add the dependency:

```
:dependencies [[com.github.mrasif/easyqrlibrary "v1.0.0"]]
```

#### Add this in your layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No QR Data"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnQRScan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="QR Scan"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Add this in your activity java files:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView tvData;
    Button btnQRScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvData=findViewById(R.id.tvData);
        btnQRScan=findViewById(R.id.btnQRScan);

        btnQRScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnQRScan: {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, QRScanner.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, EasyQR.QR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
            } break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case EasyQR.QR_SCANNER_REQUEST: {
                if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    tvData.setText(data.getStringExtra(EasyQR.DATA));
                }
            } break;
        }
    }
}
```

For customized scanner screen just add these lines when you start the scanner Activity.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, QRScanner.class);
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.IS_TOOLBAR_SHOW,true);
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.TOOLBAR_DRAWABLE_ID,R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_dark);
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.TOOLBAR_TEXT,"My QR");
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.TOOLBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR,"#0588EE");
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.TOOLBAR_TEXT_COLOR,"#FFFFFF");
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.BACKGROUND_COLOR,"#000000");
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.CAMERA_MARGIN_LEFT,50);
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.CAMERA_MARGIN_TOP,50);
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.CAMERA_MARGIN_RIGHT,50);
intent.putExtra(EasyQR.CAMERA_MARGIN_BOTTOM,50);
startActivityForResult(intent, EasyQR.QR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
```

You are done.
Ref. Link: https://mrasif.github.io/easyqrlibrary

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [KnowIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39709768/1897885)'s answer.

This is a Kotlin Google CameraX + ML Kit API based implementation.
Note that some parts of the CameraX API are still experimental as of Jan 2022.

Have a look at the [CameraX API Code Lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0) and then [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning) to understand the basics.

How it works?

Start the BarCodeScannerActivity and read the raw barcode value (RESULT_BARCODE_RAW_VALUE) from the returned activity result.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:17.0.0'

    def camerax_version = "1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha32"
}
```

activity_bar_code_scanner.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".audit.BarCodeScannerActivity" >

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

BarCodeScannerActivity.kt

```kotlin
class BarCodeScannerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewBindings: ActivityBarCodeScannerBinding
    private lateinit var cameraExecutorService: ExecutorService

    @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewBindings = ActivityBarCodeScannerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBindings.root)

        cameraExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        startCamera()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        cameraExecutorService.shutdown()
    }

    @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
    private fun startCamera(){

        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
            {
                val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBindings.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                        }
                    }

                val barcodeAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setAnalyzer(
                            cameraExecutorService,
                            BarCodeAnalyzer{ barcodes ->
                                if( barcodes.isNotEmpty() ) {

                                    val intent = Intent()
                                    intent.putExtra(
                                        RESULT_BARCODE_RAW_VALUE,
                                        barcodes.first().rawValue
                                    )

                                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)

                                    cameraExecutorService.shutdown()

                                    finish()
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }

                val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

                try {
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this,
                        cameraSelector,
                        preview,
                        barcodeAnalyzer
                    )

                }
                catch (e: Exception){}
            },

            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
        )
    }

    companion object{
        const val RESULT_BARCODE_RAW_VALUE = "barcode_raw_value"
    }
}
```

BarCodeAnalyzer.kt

```kotlin
@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
class BarCodeAnalyzer(val onSuccess: (List<Barcode>) -> Unit): ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image ?: return

        val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(
            mediaImage,
            imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
        )

        val barcodeScannerOptions = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS
            )
            .build()

        val barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(barcodeScannerOptions)

        barcodeScanner.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                onSuccess(barcodes)
            }

        imageProxy.close()
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
// ...

private val barcodeScannerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
){ result ->

    if( result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){

        val barcodeRawValue = result.data?.getStringExtra(
            BarCodeScannerActivity.RESULT_BARCODE_RAW_VALUE
        ) ?: ""

    }
}

private fun readBarcode(){
    val intent = Intent(this, BarCodeScannerActivity::class.java)
    barcodeScannerLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```