# How to create a qr code reader?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm developing an application which scans the qr code ,get the phone number from that and send sms to a particular person.. 
i searched a lot and cannot find a proper answer to that.
I need to develop it within my project by import zxing package.
please help me what are the steps to develop a qr code reader using zxing...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831050/android-how-to-read-qr-code-in-my-application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try Zbar. It is easy to integrate and use. See this reference
https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner.

Let me know if you could integrate it.

Comment: Thanks. Should use https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner now.