# adding intent filter to the manifest

Tags: android, air, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm trying to add some intent filter to my manifest in order to access the app with an QR-Code.

I've read that we must add :

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:scheme="myApp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But when I'm adding it I've got an error in Adobe Flash (when I click on publish settings).

Can you tell me if I've put the  in the wrong place please ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!-- 
    Usage:

    To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.
    <description>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text>
    </description>

    To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.
    <name>
    <text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text>
    <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text>
    </name>
-->
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0">
  <id>Aquarium</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel/>
  <filename>aquarium</filename>
  <description/>
  <name>aquarium</name>
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>aquarium.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>cpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image36x36>36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>72.png</image72x72>
    <image96x96>96.png</image96x96>
  </icon>
<activity android:name=".Main">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:host="my.app" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <supportedLanguages>fr</supportedLanguages>
</application>
```

Comment: "Application descriptor cannot be parsed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see here

[Android, How to read QR code in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831050/android-how-to-read-qr-code-in-my-application)

and here litle tutorial:

http://ribinsandroidhelper.blogspot.in/2013/03/qr-code-reading-on-your-application.html

and please click ctrl+shift+f to organized your manifest ;-)