# Android Studio - Devices Logcat showing two process

Tags: android, android-layout

Im new in Android Developing. Im trying to make a simple QR scann reader using "Barcode Scanner". So I have started some tutorials from the android.developer site. I've finish this tutorial [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage).
So I´ve moved on to what I actually wanted to do and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831050/android-how-to-read-qr-code-in-my-application) awnser on how to use Barcode Scanner in my app. I make a new Project and use that code. BUT (and here is the problem)  when I run my application, the Devices Logcat shows two process, one form the new app and the other one from the tutorial. The second package that is shown, I dont know where is taking it from. I´ve deleted the projet of the tutorial and still start the tutorial app when I run my new project.

Im using Android Studio.Any help will be appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!!! (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogCat will show the debugable processes you have running on your test device. Remove the one you want to get rid of from your test device, and it will no longer show up in the LogCat.

Comment: I was uninstalling the app doing "the basic way" (OptionMenu > Uninstall). I had to go to Application Manager in the decive and uninstall it from there. Thanks for the help!